# Laravel and MySQL .env configuration not being applied

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, configuration

I'm new to Laravel, but this is not my first app. I created a blog as my first practice project. I did not have this problem while creating the blog.

I updated the .env file to reflect the app name and database credentials. I used bash to create controllers, models, and migrate the database tables. That went just fine. The database reflected the new tables.

However, I noticed the page and meta title was not correct. It still says the old default of "Laravel". When I did ui:auth I tried to test the register page and get the error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown
> database 'laravel' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users`
> where `email` = email@gmail.com) http://localhost:8000/register Hide
> solutions Database name seems incorrect You're using the default
> database name laravel. This database does not exist.
>
> Edit the .env file and use the correct database name in the
> DB_DATABASE key.

I have edited the .env file. When I pull it up in a separate editor it shows my changes and "laravel" is nowhere in the file. How is this happening? I tried clearing my browser history in case it was a cache issue. I searched the file structure for other possible configuration files and even changed the .env.example file and it still won't show my changes. I am completely stuck with no idea how to proceed. I searched the specs to see if I could find a step I missed but I am at a loss.

```
APP_NAME=MandalanTales
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:HCZ7ZwocluPDKnz/r5nn5w51DNZRo0GI/8rRGUONRBI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mandalan
DB_USERNAME=AliciaGuitar
DB_PASSWORD=abc123
```

I removed my .env file from my .gitignore so you can see it. Please help. I'm self-taught with no in-person resources. Here is my git: [MandalanTales Git](https://github.com/AliciaAMT/MandalanTales)

Comment: Run composer dumpautoload command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you change your .env file, you need to run this at cmd

```
php artisan config:cache
```

After that, run the program with `php artisan serve`

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it had to be simple but I was fried.